# how to add delay in http request using angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

could you please tell me how to add the delay before hitting HTTP request to the server . I will give you the example .I saw a website there is `button` on click of `+` it increases the counter value and `-` it decrease the `value`.If you check the network request they are not hitting `service` on each button click or each increment value (if the user clicks `+` button many times say `5` times). They hit the service only `one` time when the user stops increment/decrement it's value for few second. I think they are using something like `debouncing` concept.
can we also implement this in angular 4 .I try to implement debouncing and so that it will not fire request on each click .

here is my code
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zf6ysz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

```
 increaseCounter(){
   this.counter = this.counter +1;
   this.requestHttp(this.counter);
  }

  requestHttp(val){
    var url ="http://api.mathjs.org/v4/?expr="+val+"*"+val;
    console.log(url);
    this.http.get(url).subscribe((res)=>{
      console.log(res ,"eee")
    })
```

example, where I saw it, is implemented `debouncing`
https://www.swiggy.com
[image]

Comment: that will not solve my problem

Comment: Here is a fork of your StackBlitz using that solution https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tdpogr?file=src/app/app.component.ts